# Tomcat & lighttpd/apache on same CentOS server

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, tomcat, lighttpd, httpd

I'm wondering whether it would be possible to setup Tomcat 6 (for hosting Confluence) and either lighttpd or Apache (for PHP things) on the same machine.

Ideally I want to have the root be PHP and /confluence to be tomcat. This is to be run from a CentOS based VPS account at a hosting company all under one domain.

I'm quite new to these things and its all a learning exercise, I'm just confused about routing and how things may be affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, your setup is possible.

setup a lighttpd or apache to serv your php stuff. then you configure a location for your confluence installation and configure it to forward the request to your tomcat with mod_proxy.

as you want it as a learning experience, this should give you the direction and the apache doc [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) should help you with the rest.

when there are more question, don't hesitate to ask, but for learning you should try for yourself first.

Comment: Wow thank-you so much! I will read through and see how I go, but I'm glad I can get this done!